React Native - TypeError: Cannot read property 'languages' of null after update on Android
I'm encountering an error after updating my React Native project. The app works on my Android device when I run yarn android, but I get an error message in the debug APK and a crash in the release APK on Android.
Here’s the error message I’m receiving in debug mode:

Update Context

React: 17.0.1 to 17.0.2
React Native: 0.64.4 to 0.67.4
compileSdkVersion: 33 to 34
targetSdkVersion: 33 to 34
buildToolsVersion: 29.0.3 to 34.0.0
Gradle classpath: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3' to
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
distributionUrl: gradle-6.7.1 to gradle-7.4

Problem Encountered
The error seems to occur due to accessing the languages property, which is null. This error doesn’t appear on iOS, only on Android in release mode.
What I’ve Tried

Checking dependencies: I verified that all dependencies are
compatible with React Native 0.67.4.
Clearing cache: I tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the
project with ./gradlew clean.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this error appears after the update or how to fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help!
